# Phrase input in C++

Tags: c++, input, phrase

I have a quick question about text input in C++. I have a code where I can input text and then output it. I want to be able to insert multiple words without using "_". For example, instead of writing "Make_breakfast", I want to write "Make breakfast".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::string s;
std::cout << "Insert task: ";
std::cin >> s;
std::cout<< s;


return 0;
}
```

Thanks for reading and please answer.